# Existence of Non-Zero Annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ is finite dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $U\neq V$. Then there exists a linear function $\phi:V\to F$ such that $\forall u\in U(\phi u = 0)$ but $\phi\neq 0$.

**Proof.** Since $V$ is finite dimensional it follows that $\dim U^0 = \dim V-\dim U>0$, where $U^0$ denotes the annihilator of $U$, since $\dim U^0>0$ it follows that $\{0\}\subset U^0$ and thus there exists some $\phi\in U^0$ such that $\phi\not=0$ .

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem is correct but the proof needs more context.  You should say that you're looking at the vector space of linear functionals before you start talking about subspaces of that space, otherwise people don't know exactly where you mean $U^0$ to live.  Also some people use the $\subset$ symbol to stand for any subset, not just a proper subset, so if the point is that $\{0\}$ is a proper subset then you should just say explicitly that $U^0$ is not $0$.

Comment: Thankyou for your critique