# Existence of a Linear functional $\phi\in U^0$ such that $\phi\neq 0$ when $U\neq V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct? I am confident of the logic of the argument i am merely unsure whether the level of detail is sufficient.

I had asked for a similar critique here [Existence of Non-Zero Annihilator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509936/existence-of-non-zero-annihilator) but now i have re-written the argument slightly since i am coming back to it after some time and could not retrace my previous line of thought.

> **Theorem.** Given that $V$ is finite dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $U\neq V$. Then there exists a linear
>   function $\phi:V\to \mathbf{F}$ such that $\forall u\in U(\phi u = 0)$
>   but $\phi\neq 0$.

**Proof.** Since $U\neq V$ it follows by theorem $\textbf{3.106}$ that $\dim V - \dim U = \dim U^0 >0$, equivalently the basis of $U^0$ will consist of at least one linear functional consequently choosing any one of the linear functionals constituting the basis of $U^0$ can serve as the required linear functional.

$\blacksquare$

**NOTE:** $U^0$ denotes the annihilator of the subspace $U$.

Comment: What is Theorem 3.106 ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman $\dim V = \dim U+ \dim U^0 $ where $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: If Theorem 3.106 says that $\dim V - \dim U = \dim U^0$, then your proof is right. Kavi's answer follows, in essence, from the same reasoning that you employ (using the fact that $V \cong V^*$ whenever $V$ is finite-dimensional or a Hilbert space).

Comment: @BerniWaterman Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating things. why use annihilators? Take a basis for U and extend it to a basis for V. You can define a linear functional by by giving arbitrary values to basis elements and extending by linearity. Simply give the value 0 to the basis elements in U and, say, 1 to the remaining.

Comment: Thankyou for your response but i merely wanted to know whether the argument above is right